# Why do we need to use constructors for initializing values when we can also do it without them?

Tags: c++

Please consider both the codes shown below. One uses a constructor to initialize the values and one does not.

Code#1

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Rectangle
{
public:
int width;
int height;
};

int main()
{
Rectangle rect1{3,4};
cout<<"Width="<<rect1.width<<endl;
cout<<"Height="<<rect1.height<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

I get the output as,

Width=3

Height=4

Code#2

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Rectangle
{
public:
int width;
int height;
Rectangle(int a,int b)
{
width=a;
height=b;
}
};
int main()
{
Rectangle rect1(3,4);
cout<<"Width="<<rect1.width<<endl;
cout<<"Height="<<rect1.height<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

I get the same output. 
My question may be simple but, why bother using a constructor when I'm getting the same output in both the cases.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't *have to* use a constructor, but if you need to do more than just assign values to the members the constructor comes in handy.

Comment: As long as the members are _public_ you can initialise them without a constructor

Comment: if the member is not default-constructible, you need to use the member initialization list method of constructing them

Answer (score 1):

the answer is pretty simple, constructor initialize, other methods assign.

The difference may not seem very major, but consider this code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Sample
{
 private:
  const int num;
 public:
  void setval(int i)
   {
    num = i;
   }
  int getVal()
   {
    return num;
   }
};
int main()
 {
   Sample s;
   s.setval(12);
   cout<<s.getVal();
 }
```

This code will give a compilation error saying that `num` is declared as const and we are trying to ASSIGN a value to `num` by making it equal to `i`.

Because `const` and `references` must be `initialized` just after `declaration`  `constructors` do this Job by `initializing` them.

Also, make your class members private, it's a good practice and much more object oriented.

So the above code should be.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Sample
{
  private:
   const int num;
  public:
   Sample( int i):num(i){}

   int getVal()
    {
     return num;
    }
};
 int main()
  {
   Sample s(12);
   cout<<s.getVal();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For such simple data types it may well not matter, however there are many non plain-old-data types that benefit from or even require initialization to be at all useful.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors have several benefits:

- Constructors allow for a public API (encapsulation). In more complicated classes, internal data which the caller should not touch may need to be initialized.

  ```
  class Foo
  {
  public:
      Foo(int x) {
          internal_data1 = some_computation1(x);
          internal_data2 = some_computation2(x);
      }

      Some_Type3 some_method(int x)
      {
          return some_computation3(x, this->internal_data1, this->internal_data2);
      }
  private:
      Some_Type1 internal_data1;
      Some_Type2 internal_data2;
  };
  ```
- There are several C++ concepts involving constructors, such as DefaultConstructible and CopyConstructible. Constructors provide a common interface so generic code can instantiate objects of different types in a uniform way.

  ```
  template<class T>
  class Some_Generic
  {
  public:
      Some_Generic(const T& t)
        : internal_t(t) // Copy constructor used
      {
          // do work...
      }
  private:
      T internal_t;
  };
  ```